# Condensed Mathematics and Analysis

Tags: general-topology, analysis, algebraic-topology, category-theory

I've just come across a Twitter thread by [Laurent Fargues](https://mobile.twitter.com/laurent_fargues/status/1407319314907156480) explaining a work by Dustin Clausen & Peter Scholze under the name Condensed Mathematics and how Condensed Mathematics can *algebraize* topology and analysis. I find it somewhat surprising (or hard to believe) that you can do such a thing. So my question is can Condensed Mathematics completely *algebraize* topology and analysis, or can it only algebraize some analytic object close to algebraic geometry?. Can we reprove theorem and inequalities in analysis such as [Mean value theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem), [Hölder's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%B6lder%27s_inequality), and so on using Condensed Mathematics?

**Update** : I crossposted to **[MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/420355/algebraizing-topology-and-analysis-via-condensed-mathematics)**.

Comment: This is probably a better fit for MO. One of the issues is that it’s not straightforward what “algebraize” means. I think that the vision of Clausen and Scholze was to construct a “nice formalism” containing topological spaces (the not-too-pathological ones, at least) but which behaved better with respect to natural algebraic operations, in particular (iirc) quotients and tensor products. I’m not quite sure what kind of goals they had, but I’d assume they’re more interested in functional analysis (with its many interesting topologies) than in more “basic” real analysis.

Comment: Hmm, maybe you're right. I'll try to post this question at mathoverflow

Comment: I thought "algebraize" referred to finding a useful functor from the category of interest to a category of algebraic objects.

Comment: Well, to be honest, I'm a novice in algebra-related subjects and have never studied category theory before. The reason I'm asking is purely out of curiosity.